# Issue in accessing zeppelin context in Apache Livy Interpreter for Zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin, livy

Is it possible to access zeppelin context (z), in Livy Interpreter for Zeppelin? If yes, then how to access it.
If no, does that mean zeppelin visualization in Livy is limited to python libraries.

How does one exchange variables between scala and python. 
It is simple if you use standard spark interpreter  in Zeppelin by using z.put and z.get

Comment: Livy doesn't support zeppelin context

Answer (score 1):

Following Hortonworks last updates is not working yet.

About visualization, you can use zeppelin built-in if using spark-sql(livy.sql) interpreter

Answer (score 1):

Livy interpreter doesn't support ZeppelinContext as of zeppelin ver 0.8.1